# In pandas.DataFrame.groupby function, can we set parameters "by=ndarray" and "level" at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In Python - ***pandas.DataFrame.groupby(by=ndarray/list, axis=1, level=1)*** - this form of call raises an error. For ***by=np.array()*** an error comes up saying `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`. While for ***by=list*** a `Keyerror` comes up.

Please look at the below sample code -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['US', 'US', 'US', 'JP', 'JP'],
                                    [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]],
                                    names=['cty', 'tenor'])
hier_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 5), columns=columns)
hier_df.groupby(by=np.array(['one','three','five','one','three']), axis=1, level=1)
```

The last line gives error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`.
Similarly the line `hier_df.groupby(by=['one','three','five','one','three'], axis=1, level=1)`also gives error `KeyError: 'one'`.

However when we do not have a Multi-index in the axis used for splitting ***by=ndarray*** works fine. Why does it not work when a multi-index is there and the ***level*** parameter is set?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The way I solved it:  nested groupby statements:

```
panzb = panzz.groupby(by=['TABLE_NUM'],as_index=False, sort=False)
for grp, panq in panzb:
       panqxx = panq.apply(lambda x: x)
       panqxy = panqxx.groupby(level=1, as_index=False, sort=False)
             for yrx, panr in panqxy:
                        panrxyy = panr.apply(lambda x: x) 
                        <more statements>
```